# App store submission guide

Tags: ios

My application is using local server  to communicate. I am looking for app store submission. How to give a demo for app store review? Is it necessary to provide my application server on cloud or public IP?

Local server : Our application server is installed inside a network and my application receives alerts from the server. Local server IP will be configured inside my application. My application also use local PBX for voice  call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Ad-hoc testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html), where you could test the app for the real time environment and using the **local-server/LAN**. You will need to create distribution profile for adhoc testing of your app and mention the devices on which you want to test the app.

If you will try to submit app with the **Demo** version of your app in the **appstore**, then it will get rejected, apple requires fully working application in order to be available on the server, so make sure that your app is tested before submitting to app-store.

Comment: App store review team need any cloud server to test my app?

Comment: First you need to test locally & when you are sure that your app is good to work, then you could provide the public server to apple.

Comment: i tested every thing with ad-hoc. Now i am looking for app store submission.My question is, App store review team need my server in cloud?

Comment: Then just submit your app in the appstore with the working public serrver address. while submitting you could mention the additional information for testing your app.

Comment: well it depends on the warning, you could try to create archive and test to submit, you will see if your archive get rejected while submitting then you will need to fix the warning messages.

Comment: i have list out one of the warning here. please check this  ld: warning: ARM function not 4-byte aligned: _SKP_Silk_resampler_down2 from /project directory/SIP/sip-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/libSKP_SILK_SDK.a(SKP_Silk_resampler_down2_arm.o)

Comment: It looks like your app is compiled or targeted for the older version of ios & compiler, and this warning is coming because you are trying to compile with the new compiler but your libraries or app is targeted for older versions.

Comment: Yes, i have included some libraries related to voice call. That libraries are throw this warning. To clear this can i replace new libraries or downgrade my compiler.

Comment: You should post a new question related the libraries warning what you are looking to upgrade or use it is completely different problem from this question, I am sure there are lots of questions related to your problem are present on SO.